# Showing limit of sequence $\left(\frac{3}{10}, \frac{33}{100}, \frac{333}{1000}, \dots\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to calculate the limit of the following sequence:

$$
(s_n) = \left(\frac{3}{10}, \frac{33}{100}, \frac{333}{1000}, \dots\right).
$$

Clearly, $(s_n) \to 1/3$, but I'm not sure how to show it rigorously. I need to be able to generate this to cases where $3$ is any integer $a \in \{ 1, 2, \dots, 9 \}$. I realize that the general limit would be $a/9$, but showing it is proving to be difficult. I'm looking for a way to express the numerator as a function of $n$, where $n$ is the "length" of the number. That is, if $a=4$ then $44$ corresponds to $n=2$ and $444$ corresponds to $n=3$. Any ideas?

Comment: $s_n= 1/3(1-(1/10)^{n-1})$

Comment: That doesn't produce the $(s_n)$ I gave

Comment: Write 333...3 as $(10^n-1)/3$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT :**

$$
s_n=3\sum_{k=1}^n10^{-k}
$$
It's clearly the summation yields geometry progression with $r=\dfrac1{10}$.

Answer (score 3):

$s_n = \dfrac{1}{3} - \dfrac{1}{3\cdot 10^n}$. So the result follows.

Comment: That doesn't produce the $(s_n)$ I gave

Comment: @MichelleRoss You sure? It seems like you have $s_1=0.3$; $\frac13-\frac1{30}=0.3$, so that works out. The rest can be checked similarly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the denominator Where $n$ is position of the digit and $a$ is any integer,since denominator is 
$$a\sum^{n-1}_{k=0}10^k=\frac{a}{9}(10^{n}-1)$$

Clearly $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a(10^n-1)}{9*10^n}=\frac{a*10^n-a}{9*10^n}=\frac{\frac{a*10^n}{10^n}-\frac{a}{10^n}}{\frac{9*10^n}{10^n}}=\frac{a-\frac{a}{10^n}}{9}=\frac{a}{9}$$